# Limpiar datos en una columna DF pandas

Tags: dataframe, float

tengo un archivo csv, con varias columnas. Todas las columnas son tipo object.
Dos columnas son altura y peso, pero en ambas hay valores con cadenas de texto.
Quiero cambiar el tipo de la columna a float, pero quiero crear dos columnas nuevas 'ALTURA1' y 'PESO1'de tipo float, respetando las columnas altura y peso originales sin que modifique ni cambie nada dentro de esas dos columnas.

Comment: los datos de altura y peso por ejemplo son los siguientes 89 kgs, 75 kgs y altura 1'89 m., 1,45m(3 pies). Por ejemplo.

Comment: Hola bienvenido. Te sugiero que leas [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

df['ALTURA1'] = df['altura'] y df['PESO1'] = df['peso'] con esto creas dos columnas con los mismos valores que las originales.

Luego puedes modificar las columnas altura y peso para pasarleas de string a float con 
df['altura'] = df['altura'].astype(float)

Espero te sirva!!!

Comment: si, me ha servido, pero ahora tengo un problema, que las columnas tienen valores nulos. Como puedo hacer para ignore esos valores nullos para cambiar el tipo a float?
PD: Muchas gracias Eduardo ¡¡

Comment: Para cambiar valores nulos por ej a 0 tienes que hacer  df.fillna(0). Eso lo que hace es rellenar con 0 los valores que son nulos. Espero te sirva.

Comment: Si, me ha servido completamente Eduardo. Lo que he hecho es seguir tus instrucciones, he rellenado los nulos a 0 con fillna. y con eso ya si que me ha dejado pasar la columna a float ¡¡
Muchas gracias por tu ayuda